# What file do I need to change to configure xdebug on my magento site?

Tags: php, magento, xdebug

I am trying to set up xdebug to work properly with my Komodo IDE. I am running a Magento site and can't find the proper php.ini file to add the configuration information to. I ran a phpinfo command and checked the location and it was on usr/local/lib/php.ini. When I did research to find where that file was located everything I read said to stay away from that file.

Also where is that file located? Is it in the public_html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use NetBeans ( it is very easy to configure with Xdebug ).

you should add these lines in your `php.ini`:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
display_errors = 1
```

Check the path `/usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/xdebug.so` and use your one.

To have a better experience with Xdebug, I suggest you to use one of those 2 plugin for your browser:

- easy Xdebug for Firefox -> https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/easy-xdebug/
- Xdebug helper for Chrome -> https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's the file you'll need to edit to both enable, and configure xDebug.  People are warning you away from that file because editing `php.ini` isn't something a novice should take on.  However, configuring xDebug isn't something a novice should take on either.

So long as you backup the file and edit only your local copy, you should be good to go.